# Google App Engine OAuth endpoints throwing 400 in production

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0

I implemented the [experimental OAuth support](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html#OAuth_Endpoints) for Google App Engine using Python, and have it working locally, but the endpoints are throwing a 400 when I deploy to appspot.

For example, the url http(s)://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken returns a 400, but locally that url pattern behaves as expected.

I have tried both http and https, and assumed that appspot handles the ssl cert.

**UPDATE**

I've been using the [OAuth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/) to test my code.  Despite documentation, it seems Registering your app *is* required.  Go [here](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html) for instructions on how to register.  According to documentation during the registration process, certificate is not required when running on App Engine.  Playground is showing more detail on the error - "signature invalid".  If I understand correctly, the signature is produced from a signature base string.  In this case I am using the base string 7DYB6MJ2s-IQcd7VJYJUmcct .

```
GET /accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Ffeed%2Fatom HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_nonce="168cfd60a93a46caa38dddfdcedd9de9", oauth_timestamp="1305315895", oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxx.appspot.com", oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fgooglecodesamples.com%2Foauth_playground%2Findex.php", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="4J5faUujE0VNaybyvFCiEPY7DQ8%3D"

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 13 May 2011 19:44:55 GMT
Expires: Fri, 13 May 2011 19:44:55 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 451
Server: GSE

**signature_invalid**
base_string:GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FOAuthGetRequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fgooglecodesamples.com%252Foauth_playground%252Findex.php%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxxxxxx.appspot.com%26oauth_nonce%3D168cf60a94caa38e2defdcedd9de9%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1305315895%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmail.google.com%252Fmail%252Ffeed%252Fatom
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

There were two things causing the 400.  First, the app was not registered.  Google's documentation says it's optional, but that is not the case apparently.  Secondly, the Request was not properly signed.  **Here is an excellent debugging tool to test your OAuth Requests: [Oauth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/)**

Comment: Did you try to dump (or log) the 400 response text? usually all the service providers give more meaning full information inside 400 code?

Comment: Unfortunately the response text is the standard 400 description, and the dashboard is not logging requests to any of the three OAuth endpoints (which I assume means that the Requests are being handled outside the scope of my app).

Comment: You only have 27 rep, how are you doing +200 rep?

Comment: Because it already takes your rep away.  I had 227 before posting this bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must register your domain in order to have OAuth working on production.

Although the following docs state that Registering is Optional:
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html

It doesn't work without the Registration since January.

Look at the link above and Register your domain/application. You don't need to submit a certificate, this is still optional.

Comment: @eduardocereto - Yep this app is not registered based on the assumption that it was optional, AND that it's on Google App Engine (and verification is automatic for say, domain registration).  I'll register now . . .

Comment: I was able to get a more specific error, "signature invalid".  The signature is created from the signature base string, in my case "7DYB6MJ2s-IQcd7VJYJUmcct".  Do I misunderstand signature creation?

Comment: The issue ended up being that the app wasn't registered (they need to update their documentation) AND the Request was not properly signed.  I found a great debugging tool to get more detailed error messaging when sending OAuth Requests:  http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/

Comment: I think you don't need signing. I don't sign my oAuth calls. But of course that if you opt to sign it should be properly signed.

Comment: Are you using Google App Engine?

Comment: Yes. I've been using it for 1 year now.

Comment: You're hitting the endpoints https://{{your-app}}/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken, https://{{your-app}}/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken and https://{{your-app}}/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken without signing the requests?

Comment: you're right these OAuth calls are signed. I'm also using AuthSub which you don't need to sign if you opt for unsecure tokens. These days OAuth is the preferable method. AuthSub is now considered a deprecated method but I don't care since I'm using it mostly on prototypes and internal projects. Sorry I mixed it up. AppEngine pretty much abstracts these calls for me.

Answer (score 0):

Which request method it is? In `dev_appserver_oauth.py` I see:

```
if method != 'GET' and method != 'POST':
  outfile.write('Status: 400\r\n')
  return
```

So it'll only work for `GET` or `POST` requests.

Comment: It's a GET.  It works locally (you're looking at DEV_appserver_oauth.py), but not when I deploy to appspot.

Comment: Okay, I looked in the SDK to search for a clue and that was the only 400 I found. So so maybe it is a production bug.

Comment: That's my only conclusion at this point too, and with I/O going on, I doubt I will find an answer anytime soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you have enabled Federated Login in your Application Settings.

[image: screenshot admin panel]

From your description it sounds like you might *just* be performing a direct GET request to `/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken` without any of the other required parameters of oAuth. This will work on the dev_appserver as it is simply a mockup of oAuth to let you flesh out your code.

See the parameters listed on the [OAuthGetRequestToken description page](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#RequestToken) for what is required and how to deal with signing. I believe you can ignore `scope` for GAE though

Comment: I was just about to ask about scope since we're using OAuth to sign Requests into the Users API.  I'll test this out, thanks.

Comment: From the documentation:  "App Engine does not support the scope and xoauth_displayname parameters. The scope for the request is the entire app."